# Regular Expression to match open and closed custom tags

Tags: php, regex, templates, tags

I'm design a custom template parser, and want to complier template 
content to php code by `{php xxx}` template syntax.

i try to use

`preg_replace('/{php\s+([^}]+)*}/', '<?php $1?>', '{php echo 'a' }');` it is can be work with single line by `{php echo 'a' }` to `<?php echo 'a' ?>`

and then change pattern support with multi line

```
$content = "
{php print_r([
    'foo' => 'bar',
])}
";
echo preg_replace('/{php\s+([^}]+)*}/', '<?php $1?>', $content);
```

now the question is how to support php function in `{php xxx}` template syntax.

source template content:

```
{php echo yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
   'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
    'items' => array_walk($menu, function($data) {
       return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::remove($data, 'items');
    }),
]); }
```

target php code

```php
<?php echo yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
   'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
    'items' => array_walk($menu, function($data) {
       return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::remove($data, 'items');
    }),
]); ?>
```

Comment: you need regex for {php some_text } ?\

Comment: Consider `{php echo "text with {$braces['key']}";}` Regex is the wrong tool for parsing complex structures.

Comment: The last `}` always closes? If so https://regex101.com/r/0ukTba/1/ i think does it. If not you need to provide more examples and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: It could even occur something like `{php $end='}'; $start = '{'; echo "$start something $end";}`. Then a concept of nesting braces using recursive expressions would break as well. You would need to take account of all cases like strings (single/double qouted, heredoc, nowdoc...) and ohters where the closing brace could occur.

Comment: Do you design your own template language or do you rely on a given one?

Comment: @user3783243 that's not working for me. i'm updated the question

Comment: You're not clear and don't answer any question in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already mentioned in the comments, regex is the wrong tool for parsing structured code.

However, as long as you can ensure that braces **always** occur pairwise and unescaped, you could use a recursive regular expression:

```
<?php
declare (strict_types=1);

$subject = <<<'EOS'
<div>{php echo yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
   'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
    'items' => array_walk($menu, function($data)
    {
      if(true)
      { 
        $x = "{}sdf{ {{}{}}{} }";
      }
      return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::remove($data, 'items');
    }),
]); }</div>

<div>{php echo yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
   'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
    'items' => array_walk($menu, function($data)
    {
      if(true)
      { 
        $x = "{}sdf{ {{}{}}{} }";
      }
      return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::remove($data, 'items');
    }),
]); }</div>
EOS;

var_dump(preg_replace( '~{php(\s([^{}]|{([^{}]*(?2))*})*)}~suU', '<?php\1?>', $subject));
```

Test it online: https://regex101.com/r/hGqVeq/2

Comment: it's work for me. thanks very much for describe and example.